# A group homomorphism proof with composition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Suppose I have groups $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, and I let $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \longrightarrow Z$ be group homomorphisms. Now, I want to prove that $g \circ f : X \longrightarrow Z$ is a group homomorphism as well. Here is my attempt:

Let $x, x' \in X$. Then,

$(g \circ f)(xx') = g(f(xx'))$

$= g(f(x)f(x'))$

$= (g \circ f)(x)(g \circ f)(x')$

Thus, $g \circ f$ is a group homomorphism.

Comment: And also recall that $g(f(1_{X}))=g(1_{Y})=1_{Z}$

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is correct. ${}{}{}{}$